# Python sort a json based on a key inside an array of dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have a structure like this:

```
[{
    "name": "apple",
    "price": "5.0",
    "record": [
        {
            "id": "008",
            "time": 1465689600
        }
    ] 
},{
    "name": "banana",
    "price": "9.0",
    "record": [
        {
            "id": "002",
            "time": 1465682600
        }
    ]
}]
```

I tried below but it gave me an error: string indices must be integers.

```
sorted(lines, key=lambda k: k['record'].get('time', 0),reverse=True)
```

How do I sort the above based on the "time" value?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd assume `lines` is the text of the file instead of the parsed json.  Once you have parsed it with `json` then the answers here will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your structure is a string. You need to convert it to a python object using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

```
import json

d = "[{'record': [{'id': '008', 'time': 1465689600}], 'price': '5.0', 'name': 'apple'}, {'record': [{'id': '002', 'time': 1465682600}], 'price': '9.0', 'name': 'banana'}]"

lines = json.loads(d)
sorted(lines, key=lambda k: k['record'][0].get('time', 0), reverse=True)
#                                       ^
```

Thereafter, the value at the key `'record'` is a list. The list has one `dict` object at index 0. So you need to access the dict object first, then you can access the values of the dictionary.

Comment: if the record was a list they would not have gotten the error `string indices must be integers.`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I later figured :)

Comment: `ast.literal_eval`... seriously?  Does the tag [tag:json] mean nothing to you?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a json, I would just decode it using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

lines = '''
[{
    "name": "apple",
    "price": "5.0",
    "record": [
        {
            "id": "008",
            "time": 1465689600
        }
    ] 
},{
    "name": "banana",
    "price": "9.0",
    "record": [
        {
            "id": "002",
            "time": 1465682600
        }
    ]
}]
'''

d = json.loads(lines)

for x in sorted(d, key=lambda k: k['record'][0].get('time', 0), reverse=True):
    print x
```

Output:

```
{u'record': [{u'id': u'008', u'time': 1465689600}], u'price': u'5.0', u'name': u'apple'}
{u'record': [{u'id': u'002', u'time': 1465682600}], u'price': u'9.0', u'name': u'banana'}
```